# How to use geocode to display the current address of the center of the google map in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps, future, geocode

I am trying to project on screen the address of the center of the google map in Flutter with the help of GeoCode but I am having problem dealing with Futures. Here is my code:

```
  class _ManageLocationPage extends State<ManageLocationPage> {
  final List<Marker> _markers = [];
  late GeoPoint chosenLocation;

  late final Future<Address> _getAddressFuture;

  Future<Address> getAddress(GeoPoint currentLocation) async {
    GeoCode geoCode = GeoCode();

    return await geoCode.reverseGeocoding(latitude: currentLocation.latitude, longitude: currentLocation.longitude);
  }

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    chosenLocation = widget.startSpot;
    _getAddressFuture = getAddress(chosenLocation);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: _getAddressFuture,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            // future is completed with data, you can build
            Address addr = snapshot.data as Address;
            return Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              children: [
                GoogleMap(
                    initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                        target: LatLng(
                            widget.startSpot.latitude, widget.startSpot.longitude),
                        zoom: 18),
                    zoomControlsEnabled: false,
                    compassEnabled: false,
                    indoorViewEnabled: true,
                    mapToolbarEnabled: false,
                    onMapCreated: (controller) {
                      final marker = Marker(
                        markerId: MarkerId('0'),
                        position: LatLng(
                            widget.startSpot.latitude, widget.startSpot.longitude),
                      );
                      _markers.add(marker);
                    },
                    onCameraMove: (position) {
                      chosenLocation = GeoPoint(position.target.latitude, position.target.longitude);
                      setState(() {
                        _markers.first =
                            _markers.first.copyWith(positionParam: position.target);
                      });
                    },

                ),
                Positioned(
                  top: Dimensions.height45 + Dimensions.height10,
                  left: Dimensions.width20,
                  right: Dimensions.width20,
                  child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: Dimensions.width10),
                      height: 50,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(Dimensions.radius20/2),
                          boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(
                                blurRadius: 10,
                                spreadRadius: 7,
                                offset: Offset(1, 10),
                                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2)
                            )
                          ]
                      ),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Icon(Icons.storefront, size: 25, color: AppColors.iconColor1),
                          SizedBox(width: Dimensions.width10,),
                          Expanded(child: SmallText(text: addr.streetAddress.toString(),)),
                        ],
                      )
                  ),
                ),
                Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 42),
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.location_on,
                        color: AppColors.mainColor,
                        size: 50,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            // handler errors
            return const Text('Error');
          }
          else {
            // future is not completed yet, display a progress indicator
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
        });
  }
}
```

When I try to run, I get the error  `type Future<Address> is not a subtype of type Address`.
When I don't use geocode and just display the latitude and longitude via printing `chosenLocation`, everything is fine and going well.

Comment: `reverseGeocoding` is a future function, so you need to use `async / await` to get its result, like in the package's example. Also consider using a `FutureBuilder`.

Comment: tried your advice but it sometimes gives me the error `Null is not a subtype of type Address`. Sometimes it does load but most of the time it gives me this error. Is it a loading problem?

I updated my code.

Comment: That can  happen because the build is running earlier than the future completes. Try to use a `FutureBuilder`.

Comment: I am already using `FutureBuilder`, which is why it renders sometimes but most cases it doesn't. I updated my code.

Answer (score 0):

In the `FutureBuilder` you need to check the status of the future (whether it is completed) before you build the `GoogleMap`. Currently, most of the times you try to build **before the future completes**.

Also, it is advised to store the future function in a member and not directly call it in the build method, so that it is not called multiple times.

Try the following:

```
class _ManageLocationPage extends State<ManageLocationPage> {
  final List<Marker> _markers = [];
  late GeoPoint chosenLocation;
  
  late final Future<Address> _getAddressFuture;
  

  Future<Address> getAddress(GeoPoint currentLocation) async {
    GeoCode geoCode = GeoCode();

    return await geoCode.reverseGeocoding(latitude: 
      currentLocation.latitude, 
      longitude: currentLocation.longitude);
  }


  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    chosenLocation = widget.startSpot;
    _getAddressFuture = getAddress(chosenLocation);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _getAddressFuture,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          // future is completed with data, you can build
          return Stack(...);
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          // handler errors
          return const Text('Error');
        }
        else {
          // future is not completed yet, display a progress indicator
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
      });
  }
```

Comment: tried this with a bit of modification.  I added Future<Address> in the `getAddress` function you created. Check my updated post.. In this case, I am always stuck at the `Text('Error') case.

Comment: Can you check with debugger what value is passed to `reverseGeocoding` and what does it return? Seems like a real error.